# MiNiFi: ListFile processor showing directory is invalid because directory does not exist

Tags: apache-nifi

i am using NiFi and MiNiFi.

**versions:**

- NiFi - 1.5
- MiNiFi - 0.4

**environment:**

- NiFi - 3 node hortonworks linux cluster.
- MiNiFi - windows 7.

i am creating the flow ListFile -> FetchFile -> RemoteProcessGroup in NiFi.

**ListFile Processor:**

- Input Directory - C:\minifi to FT

Here i have mentioned MiNiFi(windows) directory in ListFile processor. after creating it shows processor invalid because directory does not exist. As this is doing validation against the linux system, it is throwing error.

i am converting the flowfile into config file and placed in MiNiFi(windows) system.

i assumed that the error would resolve after placing in the windows system.

is my understanding correct? is not, is there any other solutions?

thanks.

Comment: Do you want to send FlowFiles generated from NiFi to MiNiFi?

Comment: i want to send files from the windows location (C:\minifi to FT) to NiFi cluster.

Comment: Are you saying that the error did not resolve once you placed the yaml on MiNiFi? Also can you try using either double backslashes like C:\\ or a forward slash like C:/ and see what happens

Comment: though the processor is showing invalid symbol while creating in NiFi linux. it is able to fetch the data after placing in the MiNiFi windows server. btw thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, this question was already resolved by the asker as follows:

> though the processor is showing invalid symbol while creating in NiFi
>   linux. it is able to fetch the data after placing in the MiNiFi
>   windows server.

Conceptually it makes sense that Nifi warns you about a directory not existing if you develop code in an environment with different directories (or in this case even a different OS) then where you deploy. Fortunately this does not hinder the deployment.